# Rust need help refactoring excessive functions

Tags: generics, struct, rust, refactoring

(i should mention im pretty new to rust)

hi! im building a 2d particle simulation game using a Vec to hold structs with the info on each particle. right now i need to write out a separate function every time i want to check if an element is touching something with a certain property. basically it searches around the particle in a circle by calculating the index of that position then compares that structs property to the target property like so:

```
//check around particle for corrodable particles
pub fn check_touch_corrode(screen: &mut Vec<Particle>, x_pos: usize) -> usize {
    if screen[calc::ul(x_pos)].corrode {return calc::ul(x_pos)}     //if particle can corrode return particle
    if screen[calc::u(x_pos)].corrode {return calc::u(x_pos)}
    if screen[calc::ur(x_pos)].corrode {return calc::ur(x_pos)}
    if screen[calc::l(x_pos)].corrode {return calc::l(x_pos)}
    if screen[calc::r(x_pos)].corrode {return calc::r(x_pos)}
    if screen[calc::dl(x_pos)].corrode {return calc::dl(x_pos)}
    if screen[calc::d(x_pos)].corrode {return calc::d(x_pos)}
    if screen[calc::dr(x_pos)].corrode {return calc::dr(x_pos)}
    x_pos                                                           //else return own position
}

//check around particle for flammable particle
pub fn check_touch_flammable(screen: &mut Vec<Particle>, x_pos: usize) -> usize {
    if screen[calc::ul(x_pos)].flammable {return calc::ul(x_pos)}   //if particle flammable return particle
    if screen[calc::u(x_pos)].flammable {return calc::u(x_pos)}
    if screen[calc::ur(x_pos)].flammable {return calc::ur(x_pos)}
    if screen[calc::l(x_pos)].flammable {return calc::l(x_pos)}
    if screen[calc::r(x_pos)].flammable {return calc::r(x_pos)}
    if screen[calc::dl(x_pos)].flammable {return calc::dl(x_pos)}
    if screen[calc::d(x_pos)].flammable {return calc::d(x_pos)}
    if screen[calc::dr(x_pos)].flammable {return calc::dr(x_pos)}
    x_pos                                                           //else return own position
}
```

this isnt really scalable considering im planning on having hundreds of elements with all kinds of different properties and interactions. im really wondering if there is any way to reduce this down to one function. ive been messing around with it on my own for a while now and havent been able to make any progress. the issue im running into is that the comparison needs to be calculated in the function and cant be passed in as far as i can tell. is there any way to fix this? like make it so i pass something that says which field of the struct i want to compare after it calculates that the structs index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find a solution!

```
pub fn check_touch(screen: &mut Vec<Particle>, x_pos: usize, criteria: impl Fn(Particle) -> bool,) -> usize {
    if criteria(screen[calc::ul(x_pos)]) {return calc::ul(x_pos)}
    //do this for every direction
}
```

then call it like

```
check_touch(screen, x_pos, |p| p.corrode)
```

credit to r/Erelde on reddit for giving me advice

Comment: FWIW an other possible improvement would be to iterate on a slice of properties (they should all be `fn(usize) -> bool`) e.g. `for dir in &[calc::ul, calc::u, calc::ur, ...] { ...` https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=794e107625a576a269b393639408b0e1 though optimiser might be somewhat less happy about it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```rust
// The function returns a tuple of indices, instead of having two functions that return one index each
pub fn check_touch_corrode_flammable(screen: &mut Vec<Particle>, x_pos: usize) -> (usize, usize) {

  let mut results : (usize, usize) = (x_pos, x_pos);

  // We keep track so that we can skip checking cells  
  let mut found_corr = false;
  let mut found_flam = false;

  let ul = screen[calc::ul(x_pos)];

  if ul.corrode {
    results.0 = ul;
    found_corr = true;
  }

  if ul.flammable {
    results.1 = ul;
    found_flam = true;
  }

  let u = screen[calc::u(x_pos)];

  if !found_corr && u.corrode {
    results.0 = u;
    found_corr = true;
  }

  if !found_flam && u.flammable) {
    results.1 = u;
    found_flam = true;
  }

  let ur = screen[calc::ur(x_pos)];

  if !found_corr && ur.corrode {
    results.0 = ur;
    found_corr = true;
  }

  if !found_flam && ur.flammable) {
    results.1 = ur;
    found_flam = true;
  }

  // Continuing like this...

  // ...

  // And then at the end:

  let dr = screen[calc::dr(x_pos)];

  if !found_corr && dr.corrode {
    results.0 = dr;
    found_corr = true;
  }

  if !found_flam && dr.flammable) {
    results.1 = dr;
    found_flam = true;
  }

  results
}
```

The main advantage of this solution is that it calculates the indices for the cells we are checking in each direction only once.

Is this more or less what you needed? Lemme know if you need more help :)

Comment: thank you so much for your response! unfortunately i dont think that will work for what im trying to do here. not only will that not scale very well, but i dont want to check for every property at once. my goal is to have a function that i can tell to look for one specific property in the surrounding particles. right now im doing that by writing out a separate function for each property but ideally id want to just have one function that accepts a variable containing the property i want to search for then scans the surrounding particles for that property

Comment: Ahh, I see! Okay, I misunderstood ^^. BTW, it's great that you managed to find a solution, congratulations! <3

Answer (score 0):

I would go in this direction, with iterators, filters, and predicates:

```
fn neighbors(x_pos: usize) -> impl 'static + Iterator<Item=usize> {
    (0..8).map(move |n| match n {
        0 => calc_ul(x_pos),
        1 => calc_u(x_pos),
        // and so on for 2-7

        _ => panic!("shouldn't get hereA"),
    })
}

fn first_corrosive_neighbor(screen: &Vec<Particle>, x_pos: usize) -> Option<usize> {
    neighbors(x_pos).filter(|p| screen[*p].corrode).next()
}

fn first_flammable_neighbor(screen: &Vec<Particle>, x_pos: usize) -> Option<usize> {
    neighbors(x_pos).filter(|p| screen[*p].flammable).next()
}
```